# C++11 exception design. Idioms and best practices changed?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I am wondering if, since C++11, where passing exceptions between threads was added and nested exceptions were added, idioms changed for exception capturing, in general.

Now we have:

1. `std::rethrow_if_nested`
2. `std::rethrow_with_nested`
3. `std::rethrow_exception`
4. `std::current_exception`

Nested exceptions are supposed to be used to not lose context for exceptions.

So now you can do something like this:

```
void open_file(std::string const & file_name) {
   try {
      std::ifstream file;
      file.exceptions(ios::failbit | ios::badbit);
      file.open(file_name);
   }
   catch (...) {
      std::rethrow_with_nested(std::logic_error("File " + file_name + 
      " could not be open"));
   }
}
```

You can get the backtrace like this, if I'm not wrong:

```
void print_backtrace(std::exception const & e, int depth = 0) {
   std::cerr << std::string(depth, ' ') << e.what() << std::endl;
   try {
      std::rethrow_if_nested(e);
   }
   catch (std::exception const & ex) {
      print_backtrace(ex, ++depth);
   }
}
```

So if you use `print_backtrace` with `open_file` it should give you the `std::logic_error` + the `ios_base::failure` in the output.

My questions are:

1. Is this idiom the "correct" way of handling exceptions in c++11, given that I want to capture all exceptions without losing context?
2. Is there a way in the `print_backtrace` function to capture exceptions with `catch (...)` to capture absolutely all?
3. I don't know why `std::rethrow_exception` is needed and I don't know when either.

Comment: I know very little about C++11 but do find it kind of strange that you'd have to rethrow in order to get at the nested exception.  I would have hoped they'd have provided some means of examining nested exceptions _without_ throwing them.  Normally exceptions represent _abnormal_ flow control, but in the context of your `print_backtrace` function, examining the nested exception is conceptually _normal_ flow control.

Comment: Yes, I also find it strange, actually, I don't know the exact design, I just remember that nested_exception is a mixin class in which your exception will be the parent class of `nested_exception`. I also see it has `[[noreturn]] void rethrow_nested() const`
and  `exception_ptr nested_ptr() const noexcept`.

Comment: @Kevin of 2013 - In C++ , exceptions are intended for normal but exceptional conditions, e.g. too little memory to allocate an array, or user entered a bad file-name.They are intended to allow processing to continue.  Abnormal conditions should be handled by terminating the program as gracefully as possible before more harm can be done.

Comment: @JiveDadson  Your definition of _abnormal_ here is a bit stronger than mine... I would perhaps have been better to say _unusual_ vs _usual_.

Comment: @Kevin - I said what I meant, and I meant what I said. :-)   I am using abnormal in the sense of "not normal", that is to say, deviating from a norm, rule, or principle.("Unknown to Dr. Frankenstien, Igor had procured an abnormal brain.") https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/normal By exceptional I mean requiring unusual attention. There is a problem with "living languages". Words get watered down. There is a relatively new use of exceptional that has made it into dictionaries, namely as a synonym for "not normal". Duh. I find it useful to retain the distinction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. I don't know that I'd call it an idiom. If by 'the "correct"' you mean something similar to how `std::vector` is the 'correct' container to use by default, I don't think there really is a particular "correct" way of handling errors. This is *a* correct way in that it's well defined behavior.

2. First you have to call `print_backtrace()` in a context that's not limited to certain exceptions, which means you have to call it in a `catch(...)` block:

```
    try {
      run();
    } catch(...) {
      print_backtrace();
    }
```

But then you don't have an exception of a known type to pass along to the function. Instead you have to write the function to access the exception differently; by throwing that exception and catching it internally (since this is the only mechanism by which you can bind a variable of a known type to an arbitrary exception).

```
void print_backtrace(int depth = 0) {
  try {
    throw;
  }

  // this block shows how to handle exceptions of some known type
  // You can have your own types instead of std::exception
  catch (const std::exception & e) {
    std::cerr << std::string(depth, ' ') << e.what() << std::endl;
    try {
      std::rethrow_if_nested(e);
    }
    catch (...) {
      print_backtrace(++depth);
    }
  }

  // Not all nesting exceptions will be of a known type, but if they use the
  // mixin type std::nested_exception, then we can at least handle them enough to
  // get the nested exception:

  catch (const std::nested_exception & ne) {
    std::cerr << std::string(depth, ' ') << "Unknown nesting exception\n";

    try {
      ne.rethrow_nested();
    }
    catch (...) {
      print_backtrace(++depth);
    }
  }

  // Exception nesting works through inheritance, which means that if you
  // can't inherit from the type, then you can't 'mixin' std::nesting exception.
  // If you try something like std::throw_with_nested( int{10} ); Then you'll
  // hit this catch block when printing the backtrace.

  catch (...) {
    std::cerr << std::string(depth, ' ') << "Unknown exception\n";
  }
}
```

3. `std::rethrow_exception` is used with `std::exception_ptr`, which is a type that can be used to transport an arbitrary exception. The only way to get at that exception is to use the normal exception handling machinery to `catch` the exception, which means you have to be able to throw that exception. That's what `rethrow_exception` does. This can be used to transport an arbitrary exception from one thread to another (as `std::future` does), or to hold an arbitrary exception as a member (as `std::nested_exception` does), or to pass an arbitrary exception as a parameter to a function which will try to print some description of the exception.

```
void print_backtrace(std::exception_ptr e) {
  try {
    std::rethrow_exception(e);
  }

  catch (const std::exception & e) {
    // ...
```